# Avoid creation of metadata tables in Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot-3

How to disable the creation of metadata tables in spring batch 5 (spring boot 3). I am seeing following exception in the logs org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_NAME = ? JOB_KEY = ?]

Trying to upgrade our batch application to use spring batch 5 (Spring Boot 3) and as part of that we made all necessary changes and seeing following error. We do not want to create metadata tables as we do not want to monitor the batch job.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The Map-based implementation of the job repository was removed in v5. If you use `@EnableBatchProcessing` or `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, you need to register a data source bean in the application context, which will be used by the default JDBC-based job repository. The datasource could be an in-memory one like H2, HSQLDB, etc. The recommended replacement of the Map-based repository is to use the JDBC one with an in-memory database, see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#job-repositoryexplorer-configuration-updates

Otherwise, you have to provide a custom implementation of `JobRepository` that throws away batch meta-data. Please note that the `JobRepository` is not only used for storing batch meta-data, but also for sharing data between steps through the step/job execution context. Therefore, you need to make sure you don't need/use that feature if you really want to use a "NoOp" job repository.

Comment: Thanks. I am little confused. I have following questions.     
1. there is no way we can avoid creating this metadata tables. sounds like we can't avoid. Please confirm                                                                                     2. Is it like we need to configure h2 also as another data source for metadata tables along with our own application db to be created  OR                            
3. just create metadata tables on our application database.

Comment: 1. No, unless you provide your own job repository implementation. 2. yes, if you really can't use the main database for batch tables AND you want to use the JDBC job repository, then you need to provide another jdbc datasource like h2 or hsqldb. 3. this is the easiest and safest solution.

Comment: We created these metadata batch tables in our application DB which is db2 and now we started seeing following Deadlock error on one of the POD (out of two pods)             DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO VSCH.batch_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
]; DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C90088;00000210;VSCH  .BJI     .00000001, DRIVER=4.25.1301. Are we missing anything?